# Deploying a watch face to device

Tags: android, wear-os, watchface

I developed a watch face and it works on Android emulator.

I have Fossil Explorist Gen4 watch which has no usb connections, only bluetooth/wifi. How can I run this watch face on my device? I exported signed apk and tried to install on my phone but it doesn't install. Also running from Android Studio is no success, I don't see the watch on the device list.

Comment: You follow this steps ? https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging

Comment: I had to connect via adb over wifi and install as sideloaded apk. Later I'll try to see in Android Studio while I am connected over Wifi. As I see, bluetooth connection doesn't display device in device list.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that first I need to connect to adb over wifi via command line, then in Android Studio my watch appears in device list and I can upload the app.